# Wicket - Getting PageExpiredException on AJAX Calls. Regular Pages work just fine

Tags: ajax, exception, wicket

We are writing an application using Wicket that uses AJAX. The application has a main window with two iFrames. The first iFrame shows a page with a map (Google Maps). The second iFrame shows a DataTable.

The main window is always visible. There are pages that are opened in their own windows (pop up windows). The windows are reused for the same page, for example link-A will reuse the same pop-up window if one is already open for that link.

The problem that we have is that when we start ‘combining’ AJAX calls with loading new pages we start getting `PageExpiredException`-s for the AJAX calls. Loading Pages (No AJAX) works fine, the AJAX calls are the problem. The following is a typical scenario:

1. Log-in and load the main page.
2. Click Link-A : This opens Page-A in a pop-up window.
3. Click Link-A 50 times: This opens Page-A 50 times reusing the same pop-up window.
4. Refresh the DataTable in the main window using AJAX: **this will throw** a `PageExpiredException`.

All this can happen in just one minute after logging in (new session), meaning the session is still valid.

We don’t know exactly what the problem is, but we managed to ‘delay’ getting this exception by increasing the value of `maxSizePerPageSession` in the `DefaultPageManagerProvider`. Looking at Wicket's source code, in the end this value is used by the `DataStore` / `PageWindowManager`.

We don’t think this is the best solution and we would like to understand what the problem is so we can address it in a better way.

We are using Wicket 1.5-RC2.

This is the stack trace:

> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.PageExpiredException: Page expired. 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:164) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getPage(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:89) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:141) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:706) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:63) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:253) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:138) 
>                   at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:194) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:244) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) 
>                   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383) 
>                   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:284) 
>                   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322) 
>                   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1684) 
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) 
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

This is the max size of the file window for that http session. After reaching it Wicket starts to override the oldest page version.
At one point this threshold is reached and page with version 1 (initial page) is deleted and page with version N is written instead. Later the Ajax call tries to find the page which holds the component with this ajax behavior and this lookup fails.

Another solution is to keep the version "alive" by pinging the page from time to time, e.g. with AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.

Comment: Martin, thanks for your answer. We are using a big number (well, we think it's big) for _maxSizePerPageSession_. We set that to be _100000000_ and we still get _PageExpiredException_ after the main pages gets refreshed a few times. As I mentioned before, these two pages get refreshed using AJAX. The thing is that sometimes we get the exception just after a few refreshes, lets say 20, and other times it works fine for a couple of hundreds. These AJAX refreshes are done automatically using JS. I'll try your suggestion of keeping the page 'alive'. Thanks again.

Comment: Martin, I think this is related to this issue: WICKET-3667.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the page 'alive' as Martin suggested is not that easy, there is a map that we can't reload (licensing issues). Further testing shows that we get the PageExpiredException just by refreshing some of the components of the main page a few times. The main page refreshes some components (AJAX) every 5 seconds. After a while, the app crashes because a PageExpiredException. I believe this problem might be related with this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3667. Any work around?

Thanks

Mauricio Lopez-Soto

Answer (score 0):

I too am suffering from this issue. I do not know the answer to this problem, but I have just created a Wicket JIRA issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4186
Let us track the progress there.